# Can this be written as ternary operator?

Tags: javascript

Just asking, can this code be written as ternary operator?

```
if (foo === "") {
  bar(1);
} else {
  bar(2);
}
```

single line ternary code:

```
(foo === "") ? bar(1) : bar(2);
```

and if yes, would you do so?

Comment: Why not `bar( foo === "" ? 1 : 2)`? That way one can see that we call `bar` either way. By the way, your single line calls `foo` instead of `bar`.

Comment: Yes, I would do that. But you can simplify it with just one call to foo : `bar(foo === "" ? 1 : 2);`

Comment: Sure it *can* be written with ternary. *Should* it? Perhaps, but that's subjective so not a good fit for the site.

Comment: I don't like the use of the ternary unless you're actually capturing the result. I prefer the first, but obviously that's subjective.

Comment: @sebcap26 Your answer is wrong. It should be bar(foo === "" ? 1 : 2);

Comment: @Conor Pender Oops ! Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator returns a value. To implement this, wrap the ternary expression up in the method parenthesis.

```
bar( foo === "" ? 1: 2);
```

Although be careful. More often than not, it's more readable to use a simple `if else` structure rather than a full ternary operator.